# Why is my 2nd div have different size from the other? They all have the same container-fluid class

Tags: html, css

In the HTML snippet below, I'm using Bootstrap and all three child divs have the same `container-fluid` class but why is the 2nd div different from other?

This is the example [Div Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ixZ3O.png). Both div1 and div4 are the same and div2 and div3 are also the same width but 1,4 and 2,3 has different div width although they are container fluid with 100%.

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="container-fluid" id="div1" style="border:5px red solid;">
        <p>This is a div filler</p>
        <table class="table-responsive nowrap bg-white rounded shadow-sm table-hover">
            <asp:GridView class="table table-striped table-hover dt-responsive" width="100%" ID="GridView1" runat="server"></asp:GridView>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="container-fluid" id="div2" style="border:5px red solid;">
        <p>This is the second Div</p>
        <table class="table-responsive nowrap bg-white rounded shadow-sm table-hover">
            <asp:GridView class="table table-striped table-hover dt-responsive" width="100%" ID="GridView2" runat="server"></asp:GridView>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="container-fluid" id="div3" style="border:5px red solid;">
        <p>This is the third Div</p>
        <table class="table-responsive nowrap bg-white rounded shadow-sm table-hover">
            <asp:GridView class="table table-striped table-hover dt-responsive" width="100%" ID="GridView3" runat="server"></asp:GridView>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: they are actually the same. Its just your border is making it look like it is small and have bigger border. If you put a break in each div you'll see them separately.

Comment: in your codes `div`s likes similar

Answer (score 0):

```
 <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div id="div1">
                <p>This is a div filler</p>
                <table class="table table-bordered table-responsive nowrap bg-white rounded shadow-sm table-hover">
                    <asp:GridView class="table table-striped table-hover dt-responsive" width="100%" ID="GridView1" runat="server"></asp:GridView>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div id="div2">
                <p>This is the second Div</p>
                <table class="table table-bordered table-responsive nowrap bg-white rounded shadow-sm table-hover">
                    <asp:GridView class="table table-striped table-hover dt-responsive" width="100%" ID="GridView2" runat="server"></asp:GridView>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div id="div3">
                <p>This is the third Div</p>
                <table class="table table-bordered table-responsive nowrap bg-white rounded shadow-sm table-hover">
                    <asp:GridView class="table table-striped table-hover dt-responsive" width="100%" ID="GridView3" runat="server"></asp:GridView>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: still the same :c check out the div example for the result

Comment: I have updated the code. Please check it. Here I removed the border style. And add `table, table-bordered` class on the table tag.